# Android-приложение выдаёт ошибку при отладке через usb

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Я пытаюсь считать информацию о wifi сети, так же, как описано на [сайте](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_wi_fi.htm),
но при запуске приложения на устройстве появляется ошибка.

Вот log файл:

> 03-02 19:19:11.196: W/dalvikvm(16049): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c4e1f8)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wifi3/com.example.wifi.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.wifi.MainActivity
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.wifi.MainActivity
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
> 03-02 19:19:11.196: E/AndroidRuntime(16049):    ... 11 more

Comment: у вас проблема с именами пакеджей. Проверьте, в каком пакедже находится ваш MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> com.example.wifi3/com.example.wifi.MainActivity

Походу не совпадает имя класса активити декларированное в манифесте с реальным его положением в каталоге. То есть или пакет должен быть `com.example.wifi` или декларация в манифесте должна быть `com.example.wifi3`

Answer (score 0):

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo) нашел похожую проблему. Советуют проверить наличие activity в манифесте

```
< activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

А же проверьте разрешения

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```